# Accessing a local device with different subnet

Tags: ubuntu, android, lan

I have three android phones say A,B and C. A is working as a hotspot and both B and C are connected to it. The phone C is connected to a PC via USB Tethering.Is there any way to access the PC without internet through phone B?.

Comment: Do you mean "through phone C"?

Comment: No I mean phone B